# Finding data frame rows that contain a certain character only once

Tags: r

Sorry for potential duplicating, but I don't really know how to formulate my request. I work on R and I would like to be able to identify data frame cells that contain a certain character only one time.

In my `df` I have a column `a` that contains formulas stored as strings, e.g.

```
#  a  
1  y~x1+x2  
2  y~x2+x3  
3  y~x1+x2+x3  
4  y~x2+x4 
5  y~x1+x3+x4
```

and I would like to keep rows which formulas in column `a` have 2 explanatory variables, i.e. that only contain one "+". The idea would be to filter and to add kind of a dummy, such as the output would be like

```
#  a           b   
1  y~x1+x2     1   
2  y~x2+x3     1   
3  y~x1+x2+x3  0   
4  y~x2+x4     1   
5  y~x1+x3+x4  0
```

Hope that's clear enough. Thanks for helping,
Val

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gsub` with `[^+]` to extract all `+` and `nchar` to get their number.

```
x$b <- +(nchar(gsub("[^+]", "", x$a)) == 1)
x
#           a b
#1    y~x1+x2 1
#2    y~x2+x3 1
#3 y~x1+x2+x3 0
#4    y~x2+x4 1
#5 y~x1+x3+x4 0
```

Or use `gregexpr`:

```
lapply(gregexpr("\\+", x$a), length) == 1
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or using it with `lengths` as suggested by @ThomasIsCoding:

```
lengths(gregexpr("\\+", x$a)) == 1
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or using `grepl`:

```
grepl("^[^+]*\\+[^+]*$", x$a)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Or with `strsplit`:

```
sapply(strsplit(x$a, ""), function(y) sum(y == "+")==1)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Data:

```
x <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="a
1  y~x1+x2
2  y~x2+x3
3  y~x1+x2+x3
4  y~x2+x4
5  y~x1+x3+x4", stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: great solution gallery! +1

Comment: I used the `nchar` solution and everything's ok, thanks for it!

Answer (score 1):

Another base R solution is using `gregexpr`, i.e.,

```
df$b <- +(lengths(gregexpr("\\+",df$a))==1)
```

such that

```
> df
           a b
1    y~x1+x2 1
2    y~x2+x3 1
3 y~x1+x2+x3 0
4    y~x2+x4 1
5 y~x1+x3+x4 0
```

**DATA**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c("y~x1+x2", "y~x2+x3", "y~x1+x2+x3", "y~x2+x4", 
"y~x1+x3+x4")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", 
"3", "4", "5"))
```

Answer (score 1):

A third base alternative assuming there is always at least two predictors in the formula.

```
df$b <- +(!grepl("\\+.*\\+", df$a))

df
           a b
1    y~x1+x2 1
2    y~x2+x3 1
3 y~x1+x2+x3 0
4    y~x2+x4 1
5 y~x1+x3+x4 0
```